# Synchronize two branches which have diverged

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have two branches B1 and B2 (i want to keep both) but I have made developments in both of them recently. 
I would like to import changes from B1 to B2 and changes from B2 to B1 (changes are in different places so there should be no conflict).
What is the best way to do that please ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Merge both ways :

```
git checkout B1
git merge B2
git checkout B2
git merge B1
```

At this point `B1` will miss only the last merge commit but their code will be the same.

---

Alternatively, you could also just merge one then move the other ref :

```
git checkout B1
git merge B2
git branch -f B2 B1
```

but note that this would rewrite `B2`'s history so if you already shared it (pushed on a remote server where it has been pulled by someone else) it might be an unconvenient process, go for the first method.